# jquery click loop

Tags: jquery, loops, click

I was trying to make simple click loop with some delay, can you tell me where Im wrong? Here's my code:

```
    function loop(time) {
        $('.navNextSlide').delay(time).click(function() {
            loop(time);
        });
    }
    loop(1000);
```

thanks,
M

Comment: Please tell us what happens at the moment - do you get an error? Nothing happens? The wrong thing happens?

Comment: what is wrong? error or what?

Comment: There is no error in console and the code inside the loop is not executed.

Comment: Use setTimeout() function. Here is some good examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `window.setInterval()`.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.navNextSlide').click();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function loop(time) {
        $('.navNextSlide').delay(time).click(function() {
            setTimeout("loop()",time);
        });
    }
    loop(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? It's far more practical:

```
var loopTime = 1000;

var interval = setInterval(loop,loopTime);

function loop() {
    $('.navNextSlide').trigger('click');
}

$('.navNextSlide').click(function() {       
   //what you want to happen when click occurs
});
```